# linking template metaprogramming issue with g++

Tags: templates, c++11, g++, clang, metaprogramming

I am porting some windows code that compiles like would expect under msvc 10, but I am having trouble with it linking under g++ 4.8 and/or clang 3.5.

**masks.h**

```
#ifndef MASKS_H
#define MASKS_H

#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>

namespace MASKS
{
// ------------------------------------------------- power function
template<class TYPE, uint32_t Base, uint32_t Power>
struct Pow
{
    static const TYPE tmp = Pow<TYPE, Base, Power / 2>::value;
    static const TYPE value = (Power % 2 == 0) ? (tmp * tmp) : (Base * tmp * tmp);
};

template<class TYPE, uint32_t Base>
struct Pow<TYPE, Base, 0>
{
    static const TYPE value = 1;
};

template<class TYPE, uint32_t Base>
struct Pow<TYPE, Base, 1>
{
    static const TYPE value = Base;
};

// ------------------------------------------------- mask function
template<class TYPE, int Val>
struct Mask
{
    static const TYPE value = Pow<TYPE, 2, Val>::value - 1;
};

template<class TYPE>
struct Mask<TYPE, 64>
{
    static const TYPE value = 0xffffffffffffffff;
};

//#define MASK(z, n, text) (MASKS::Mask<uint64_t, n>::value)

static const boost::array<uint64_t, 4> s_Masks = 
    boost::assign::list_of<uint64_t>
    (MASKS::Mask<uint64_t, 0>::value)
    (MASKS::Mask<uint64_t, 1>::value)
    (MASKS::Mask<uint64_t, 2>::value)
    (MASKS::Mask<uint64_t, 3>::value)
    //BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO (0, 65, MASK, text)
    ;

inline uint64_t GetMask (size_t iLen) { return MASKS::s_Masks[iLen]; }
}  // namespace MASKS

#endif // MASKS_H
```

**main.c**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "masks.h"

int main (int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[])
{
    std::cout << "63 bit mask: " << std::hex << std::showbase << MASKS::GetMask (63) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it will not link and gives the following error:

```
g++ masks.cpp -o mask -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
tmp/ccYZ0MMb.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
masks.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `MASKS::Mask<unsigned long long, 0>::value'
masks.cpp:(.text+0xea): undefined reference to `MASKS::Mask<unsigned long long, 1>::value'
masks.cpp:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `MASKS::Mask<unsigned long long, 2>::value'
masks.cpp:(.text+0x10f): undefined reference to `MASKS::Mask<unsigned long long, 3>::value'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not sure what I am forgetting here. I expected the TMP objects/functions to get translated to values by the compiler and stored in the array of masks I am trying to build. I am rusty on my g++ syntax I guess.  Can anyone see what I've done wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: MSVC has a language extension that does not require a definition for a static data member, even if it is odr-used. clang++ and g++ comply here to the Standard and require a definition. You can either prevent odr-use (by lvalue-to-rvalue conversion or using an `enum` instead of a static const data member) or provide a definition.

Comment: @dyp, that is indeed the problem, thanks. However, when i made the fix it stopped working for msvc. It seems that msvc wants the inline definition.

Comment: *"However, when i made the fix"* What fix?